# The django rest framework is not able to recognize the User defined as foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to save a user profile information in a django model. The model is defined as follows

```
class UserProfile(models.Model): 
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  reg_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
  family = models.CharField(max_length=30,  blank=True)
  phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=20,  blank=True)

  def __str__(self) :
    return self.name + self.family
```

The serializer for the model is defined as:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
  class Meta: 
    model= UserProfile
    fields = ['user', 'reg_date', 'name', 'family', 'phoneNumber']
```

and the view is as follows:

```
class UserProfileView(viewsets.ViewSet): 
  def create(self, request): 
    UserProfile.objects.create(user = request.user)
```

I'm sending a post request using axios as follows:

```
const a = await ProfileAPI.post('',
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': mytoken
          }
        })
```

in which *mytoken* is a logged in user token provided by dj-rest-auth API. Although the token is OK and the UserProfileView is executed by the request, I got the following error by the django rest:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000001F069C59190>": "UserProfile.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Am I missed something? Is there any problem with my request or view?
Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: you've to use some authentication mechanisms to set the user instance to the `request.user` dictionary. See [How Django Rest Determines Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined) Otherwise the request user is always `Anonymous`

Comment: I added the authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, ) to the view but I am getting the same error!

Comment: while using the `TokenAuthentication` we've to send the authentication token header during the request. This token can be grabbed as shown in the docs here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 0):

#### How authentication is determined

The authentication schemes are always defined as a list of classes. REST framework will attempt to authenticate with each class in the list, and will set `request.user` and `request.auth` using the return value of the first class that successfully authenticates.

If no class authenticates, `request.user` will be set to an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`, and `request.auth` will be set to `None`.

The value of request.user and request.auth for unauthenticated requests can be modified using the UNAUTHENTICATED_USER and UNAUTHENTICATED_TOKEN settings.

#### Settings

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

#### Views

```py
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': str(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': str(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

#### How to send request with token

```js
// get the token from where you've stored, localStorage is just an example
const token = localStorage.getItem("myToken")
const response = await axios.post('my-api/', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Token ${myToken}`
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in settings.py
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = '(app name).UserProfile'`